# Convert GMT time to Local time using Java

Tags: java, android, string, date, parsing

I have `Thu Mar 24 13:00:00 GMT+07:00 2016`.

I want to convert it to `Thu Mar 24 22:00:00 pm`. How can I do that using `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried anything so far? If you're using SimpleDateFormat, that suggests you've got some code - please show what you've got, and what the result is so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d hh:mm:ss aa");
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

- `E` stands for a day as word
- `MMM` stands for a shortened month
- `d` stands for a number of the day
- `hh:mm:ss` is the classic time format
- `a` is the am/pm marker

Answer (score 1):

You should first parse the text intput:

```
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
            .parse("Thu Mar 24 13:00:00 GMT+07:00 2016");
```

then format to local time in new format

```
    String str = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(date);
```